# slideDown and slideUp using DRY method

Tags: jquery

My code is working but I was wondering how I could write it using a DRY or clean method.

```
$(".toggle").hide();

$(".contact").click(function() {
    $(".toggle").slideDown("slow");
    $(".buttons").hide();
});

$(".cancel").click(function() {
    $(".toggle").slideUp("slow");
    $(".buttons").show();
});
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/Hx65Q/1374/)**

Comment: Can you show an example of what you would expect even on pseudocode? I see this as simple as it can be

Comment: Your previous answer was right. That was what I was expecting. Why did you delete it?

Comment: because I was using any of the two buttons to slide up or down and you seem to want each button to have an unique responsability (slide up OR slide down but not both)

Comment: Oh ok, yeah that's right. Does my example help?

Comment: yeah, it helps but I still think this can't be simpler, any change to make simpler will make it more complex :)

Comment: Ok I updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/Hx65Q/1374/

Comment: now you can use my solution since only one button is visible. I'll update

Comment: Thanks. I also have another question but I will post as new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since only one button is visible you could use [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) and [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$(".toggle").hide();

$(".cancel, .contact").click(function() {
    $(".toggle").slideToggle("slow");
    $(".buttons").toggle();
});
```